# No internet on Galaxy Tab 2 10.1 when connected to Windows Wifi Hotspot

Tags: wi-fi, 4.2-jelly-bean, windows, wifi-hotspot, samsung-galaxy-tab-2-10.1

I have followed the instructions to set up a virtual wifi hotspot on my Windows 10 machine (connected via ethernet to router) from [LifeHacker](http://lifehacker.com/turn-your-windows-10-computer-into-a-wi-fi-hotspot-1724762931). I have connected my iphone and Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 10.1 (P5110 running Android 4.2.2) to the new wifi hotspot. My iphone can access the internet fine, however my tablet cannot.

I have tried to use the default browser and chrome on my tablet and both say the web page is not available (chrome shows the dino and DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NO_INTERNET message).

Why is my tablet not connecting to the internet and how do I fix it?

[Edit]

A co-worker has connected his Windows 10 pc and HTC One (running 5.0) to my hotspot and both are fine on the internet.

[Edit]

After restarting the router the tablet can access the internet via the pc. Did restarting the router fix the issue or is that just a coincidence? Why could other devices connect to my pc except for my tablet?